# Github api find a file with at least n lines of code or of size m

Tags: github, github-api

I have to write texts with large files in terms of lines of code and size.

There is a way on github to find a file in a specific language with at least n lines of code or of size m.

For example, for a `rust` file I do this: https://github.com/search?q=language%3Arust+&type=code

But I don't know how to filter by file size or lines of code and I can't find anything.

Comment: You can [use regular expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-regular-expressions) in your search — for example: to find rust files with at least 999 newlines: [`language:rust /([^\n]*\n){999}/`](https://github.com/search?q=language%3Arust+%2F%28%5B%5E%5Cn%5D*%5Cn%29%7B999%7D%2F&type=code) — if that answers your question, I can write it as one, but I think the direct answer is: those metrics aren't filterable criteria for searches.

Comment: @jsejcksn: if it worked correctly I could consider the problem as a solution if I do something like this: `language:rust /([^\n]*\n){1010}/` doesn't find anything for me.
Even if there are elements with rows of 1260 or 5346.
A solution beyond what you say could be to consider the size of the single file, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @jsejcksn: I also tried this but it doesn't work: `language:rust /(?:\n[^\n]*){1000,}/`

Comment: `language:rust /(?:\n[^\n]*){1000,}/` works for me, however anything above 1000 fails as that appears to be the limit of the engine. I tried to double the matching with another newline with `language:rust /(?:\n[^\n]\n[^\n]*){1000}/` which should grant me 2000-line files, however it returned nothing, and a message `Results are not exhaustive because query was too expensive to satisfy, consider refining your query!`.